# on web browser jsp file prints only it's name. it doesn't print the string content from body tag. i've tried many ways but nothing works for me

Tags: spring-boot

i am a new to spring framework. i have started to learn Spring Boot,In Spring Tool Suite-4 Spring boot application, home.jsp or any .jsp file, I can't display in the browser rather file name is displayed as a string in the browser. i have used all the required dependencies in pom.xml file

1.Controller Class

```
package com.telusko.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    @RequestMapping("home")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi..");
        return "home.jsp";
    }
```

2.Home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        I love java
</body>
</html>
```

3.Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.telusko</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyWebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.46</version>
</dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-parameter-names -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.46</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.46</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.46</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.46</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    
</build>

</project>
```

4.In Browser Output

```
home.jsp
```

5.application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
```

6.In Console

```
2021-05-29 10:13:35.322[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.telusko.demo.MyWebAppApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting MyWebAppApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-JF5BSMC with PID 12916 (C:\Users\Lakshmana Sai\SpringWorkspace\MyWebApp\target\classes started by Lakshmana Sai in C:\Users\Lakshmana Sai\SpringWorkspace\MyWebApp)
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:35.326[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.telusko.demo.MyWebAppApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The following profiles are active: @spring.profiles.active@
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:36.898[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:36.912[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:36.912[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:37.306[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:37.324[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:37.325[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1914 ms
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:37.961[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:37.975[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.telusko.demo.MyWebAppApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started MyWebAppApplication in 3.253 seconds (JVM running for 4.319)
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:37.977[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
[2m2021-05-29 10:13:37.979[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation. It indicates that what is returned from the method should be used as the body of the response which is not what you want.

You should also change the string that is returned from `"home.jsp"` to `"home"`. The `.jsp` suffix isn’t needed.

Lastly, add `<packaging>war</packaging>` as JSPs are not supported with jar packaging.

Comment: i have tried as you said but it does not work..i got an error on browser

Comment: Without knowing what the error was, it's going to be hard to help you further. Perhaps you can update your question with some more details or ask a new one now that you've hopefully moved past the `@ResponseBody` problem.

Comment: when i removed @ResponseBody, on the browser shows.... White Label Error  This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Comment: After adding spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency in my pom.xml and adding spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp
My problem Solved. Thank You Andy Wilkinson for responding to me,